# Pop alert on sending mail to external domain

Tags: lotus, lotus-formula

Whenever any user is sending mail to external id there should be a Pop up while sending mail to external email IDs.

Comment: More details... What coding u hav done til now???

Comment: Possible, but only for very experienced LotusScript- programmers that know the internas of the Mail- template... (of course depending of what you want to achive, a popup can be made with one line of formula, but I don't think, that the popup is the only function)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some changes to your Notes Mail template on server and update all user mail databases with the template.

*How to add requested functionality to Notes mail template?*

Open Notes Mail template in Designer and go to form "Memo". Look here for the event `Querysend()` or `Postsend()`.

Add your code to `Querysend()` if you want to "warn" the user that he's going to send an email outside company. You could ask user if he wants to send email anyway. In case of YES leave `Querysend()` with `true` in case of NO with `false`.

Add your code to `Postsend()` if you just want to notice user about sending an email outside company.

The code itself should look at the fields `SendTo`, `CopyTo` and `BlindCopyTo` and decide if it is an external email address included or not. If yes it shows a prompt box with the help of `Prompt` or `MessageBox`.

If you use `Querysend()` event then you have to write your code in LotusScript because there is already code included. Only in case of `Postsend()` you are able to use Formula language (@Prompt()) or JavaScript (alert()) alternative.

When your changes work for form "Memo" then you have to put same code in forms "Reply" and "Reply With History" and maybe in some other memo forms in own applications too.